# AWS Bitnami Parse Server - Adding HTTP authentication makes my apps in parse dashboard 'unauthorized'

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have recently setup an EC2 Bitnami Parse Server and everything was working fine. I was able to access my apps through the dashboard.

Then I decided to add HTTP authentication to ensure I'm the only one with access to my parse dashboard. I followed the instructions here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/parse/#how-to-enable-http-authentication-for-the-parse-dashboard

Now after setting up a user/pass for my Parse dashboard and restarting the Parse service, I can't seem to access my apps in the dashboard anymore. I'm always getting this 'server unreachable - unauthorized' status. I've attached a screenshot of this. [image: screenshot]

I've already tried rebooting the instance in the AWS console but still no dice.

So for now, I've disabled HTTP authentication so that I can access my apps in the dashboard.

Why is this so? Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue related with having both Parse and Parse Dashboard in the same server. There is an opened issue in GitHub:

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-dashboard/issues/394

We (Bitnami) opened a task to fix it and one of our engineers will work on fixing on it. Thanks in advance for your consideration and patience. We will notify you about our progress.

In the meantime, please revert the changes done on /opt/bitnami/apps/parse/htdocs/server.js and restart Parse Server and you should be able to use the Dashboard again.

Comment: I see... I look forward to that fix then.